# Can I perform multigroup SEM analysis (7 construct, 28 indicators) with only 160 sample?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, small-sample

I do research about leadership on social enterprise for my thesis. There is 1 endogenous construct (leadership effectiveness) and 6 exogenous constructs. Each construct has 4 indicators. I'd like to examine whether there is a difference in results between the growing and established enterprise. Unfortunately, due to missing data and non-response rate, the sample that can be collected is only 160. Can I perform a SEM multigroup analysis with this amount of sample, or is there any tool which can 'increase' the sample size?

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is no. You couldn't do a model this large and complex with a single group.

Comment: "Can I perform a SEM multigroup analysis with this amount of sample, or is there any tool which can 'increase' the sample size?" is the question. One other answers says some things that might help, but they are clutching at straws. The answer to the question is "No". I'm not sure what else to add. I don't require clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly tricky. You could consider:

- [Bayesian Structural Equation Modelling](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22962886) using informative priors
- [Parcelling](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1207/S15328007SEM0902_1?tab=permissions&scroll=top) your indicators in order to decrease the model complexity
- Performing a [power analysis](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4334479/) to check the power of your model

Comment: I'd second parcelling indicators. In this case, if you could reduce each of the constructs to a simple sumscore then you would be able to analyse the data with a multiple regression, where 160 observations may be much more likely to be sufficient.